# Creating a composed functions with pure functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, pure-function

I am trying to get my head around both composed functions and pure functions.

I have an object with a mixture of data. On some values I need to:

1. remove the value's units
2. parse string to integer
3. Convert to value decimal

I have written three functions attempting to make them pure in the sense that they only do one thing but strictly speaking, they are mutating state. I'm not sure how to avoid mutating state though and if this technically makes it not a pure function?

My three "pure" functions are:

```
function parseValue(val) {
    return typeof val === 'number' ? val : parseInt(val)
}

function stripUnits(val) {
    return typeof val === 'string' ? val.match(/\d+/)[0] : val
}

function convertToDecimal(val) {
    return val / 100
}
```

I am then trying to compose these functions into one function with the help of [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) `compose()`

```
function prepValue(val) {
    return compose(stripUnits, parseValue, convertToDecimal)
}
```

When I try run this `console.log("prepValue", prepValue(weather.current.temperature))` I get the following in the terminal:

```
prepValue function (){var n=arguments,e=n[0];if(o&&1==n.length&&of(e))return o.plant(e).value();for(var u=0,n=r?t[u].apply(this,n):e;++u<r;)n=t[u].call(this,n);return n}
```

So the main things is,

1. How can I make my three functions "pure"
2. How can I compose these functions into 1

Comment: `[f1, f2, f3].reduce( (f, g) => value => f(g(value)) )`

Comment: @destoryer Is this to replace the compose function?

Comment: `prepValue` returns a composed function. If you want to call it immediately, use: `return compose(stripUnits, parseValue, convertToDecimal)(prepValue)`. Or, i.e.: `const prepValue = compose(f1, f2, f3)`

Comment: `but strictly speaking, they are mutating state` - Are they? I don't think they are....

Comment: @Stretch0 Yes, that returns something like `f(x) => g(h(i(x)))`

Comment: @Jamiec I guess you're correct, they aren't mutating state at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only mistake you made is not calling the resulting composed method with `val` as the argument:

```
function prepValue(val) {
    return compose(stripUnits, parseValue, convertToDecimal)(val);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jamiec. Are you saying the three functions are "pure" then?

Comment: Very smart and nice solution. Cheers!

Comment: @Jamaic Compose appears to compose the functions in reverse. I found `const prepValue = compose(convertToDecimal, parseValue, stripUnits)` seemed to yield the result I required

Answer (score 1):

You need to "create the function composition" before calling it.

```js
function parseValue(val) { console.log(val)
    return typeof val === 'number' ? val : parseInt(val)
}

function stripUnits(val) { console.log(val)
    return typeof val === 'string' ? val.match(/\d+/)[0] : val
}

function convertToDecimal(val) {console.log(val)
    return val / 100
}

function prepValue(val) {
    return _.compose(stripUnits, parseValue, convertToDecimal)(val);
}

console.log("prepValue", prepValue('001232'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.fp.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why does `prepValueComp` take `val` and not use it?

Comment: Thanks, that resolves the issue with calling the composed function but I am with @Jamiec, why does `prepValueComp` take `val` and not use it?

Comment: Still unsure about the pure functions as well. How can I avoid mutating state on those functions?

Comment: @Jamiec it just composes the functions (no need to handle any arguments) - but I updated the answer to match your solution, since it's way easier to understand.

Comment: @Stretch0 Pure function always return the same output (given the same input) AND produces no side effects. Seems to me that your functions respect those conditions, so you will be fine ;D.

Comment: Thanks @rafaelcastrocouto. Good to know